# Merge width x height x 3 numpy uint8 array into width x height x 1 uint32 array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a width x height x 3 channel array, like

```
import numpy as np
aa = np.array(np.random.randint(0, 255, 300),  dtype=np.uint8).reshape((10, 10, 3))
```

Now, I want to put these numbers in an `np.uint32` array. I can do it by creating a new array and bitwise shift and or operations. However I would like to learn if there is a cleaner way by creating a numpy view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.view` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html):

```
In [94]: X = numpy.array([10, 2, 4, 8], "uint8")

In [95]: X.view("uint32")
Out[95]: array([134480394], dtype=uint32)
```

In your case, you first need to add a plane of zeros, or whatever you want as the last 8 bits:

```
In [110]: aa = np.array(np.random.randint(0, 255, 300),  dtype=np.uint8).reshape((10, 10, 3))

In [111]: concatenate((aa, zeros(shape=(10, 10, 1), dtype=aa.dtype)), 2).view("uint32")
```

In some cases, you may need to pass your data through `numpy.ascontiguousarray` first, in particular in case any of the following applies:

> Views that change the dtype size (bytes per entry) should normally be avoided on arrays defined by slices, transposes, fortran-ordering, etc.

See the [view documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html).

You may also want to be careful about the endianness of your `uint32` (`<u4` or `>u4`).